# Degree of a finite field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $i,\sqrt{3}\in\mathbb{C}$. I know that both are algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Hence $[\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{3}):\mathbb{Q}]=\deg(i\sqrt{3},\mathbb{Q})$. This is equal to 2 since $\mathrm{irr}(i\sqrt{3},\mathbb{Q})=x^2+3$.

But now I am a little bit confused how to find the irreducible polynomial such that I can compute $[\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{3}):\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{3})]$ which is equal the degree of that polynomial.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt 3) = \mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt 3, i)$.

It remains hence to calculate the degree of the simple field extension $\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt 3, i)/\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt 3)$.

We find that $i$ is a zero of the polynomial $X^2+1$, which is still irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt 3)$. Hence the degree is 2.

Comment: Is $irr((i,\sqrt{3}),\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{3}))=X^2+1$? If we apply $\sqrt{3}$ to $X$ it does not give $0$, only true for $i$.

Comment: But we are looking at the field $\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt 3, i)$ over the field $\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt 3)$, so there is no need to apply $\sqrt 3$ to $X$. More precisely, only the irreducible polynomial *of an element* is defined. It makes only sense to write $\mathrm{irr}(L, K)$ if $L/K$ is a *simple* field extension, i.e. there is $\alpha \in L$ such that $L=K(\alpha)$. My answer solves the problem by rewriting $\mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt 3)$ in such a way that the required extension becomes a *simple* extension.

Comment: Oh I see... OK. Many thanks, that cleared my confusion :)